# Breaking the Python code into multiple lines

Tags: python, arrays, list

how can we write this single statement code into multiple lines?

I can understand only for loop written in multiple lines. Anyone, please break this code into multiple line code.

```
amp.append([amp[i] for i in ida])
```

Comment: Why do you need that? Is your existing code not doing what you expect it to? If it is not, the answers will be incorrect too.

Comment: Perhaps you should start with some sample data and expected result.  From my reading, if `amp = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `ida = [1, 3]`, then `amp.append([amp[i] for i in ida])` would result in `amp` having the value `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [2, 4]]`. Is that what you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By a `for` loop:

```
l = []
for i in ida:
    l.append(amp[i])
amp.append(l)
```